# Continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

For real $x$, let $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\cos(x)\right)^{2n}$. Then what about the continuity of $f(x)$? Is $f(x)$ continuous everywhere?

Comment: What is $f(0)$? What is $f(x)$ for $x\ne0$ and close to $0$?

Comment: $f(0)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[\cos 0]^{2n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 1^{2n}=1$. But, in the other case...

Answer (score 2):

$f(0)=1$  and $f(x)=0\forall x\ne n\pi$  as $|\cos x|\le 1$ so your $f$ is not continuous